Good chess book for kids
My nephew has just turned 6 and I was wondering what is a good book for him to learn chess at his age as there are so many out there.
He is very smart indeed for his age and particularly good at mathematics.

Please take a few minutes to visit the Help Center (https://chess.stackexchange.com/help) to find out what type of questions are welcome. Opinion based questions like this are not on topic.

If this is a gift, there's a book called "How to Beat Your Dad At Chess" (Chandler) which is... probably not the best-written introduction, I found it kinda dry. But it's got the benefit of being a fun, cheeky 'uncle to nephew' gift (especially if you're brothers with his dad)

The Chess Steps series, official method of the Royal Dutch Chess Federation (source), has specific books for children aged 4–8 called Stepping Stones.

Peter Giannatos' Everyone's First Chess Workbook is also a good first puzzle book once the rules of chess are fully understood (e.g., piece movements).


How to Beat Your Dad at Chess is a good book for beginning players to learn (mostly) checkmating patterns and tactics. It presents 50 such situations. Each one is presented on two pages of the book. The puzzles are short - usually with an intermediate position presented - so are easy to follow and solve without the need to pull out a chess board and pieces.
Here is the Amazon listing if you wish to purchase it there.
Good luck to your nephew. When my kid was about 10 they got hooked on chess for a while. It was about that same time that they started to excel in school (especially math and science) after being an average student until that point. I believe that chess helped them learn to focus and study better, which aided the improvement.

I don't know how much your nephew knows about chess, but the ChessKids has amazing books for beginners and specifically kids, so you should take a look at it!
Here in this great page you can find a lot of options: https://www.chesskid.com/learn/articles/chess-books-kids

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
